# Swift - How do I count the occurrences of a specific character in a String?

Tags: swift

Let's say that I have a specific String like follows:

```
var myName = "Jane Doe"
```

I want to count the number of times that a specific character shows up in the String, such as the amount of times that the letter "e" shows up. How can I do this?

Comment: While to an approach to recommend here, such a problem can solved via computing the difference in length between a string (or sequence) and the same string (or sequence) with the specific characters (or items) removed. In pseudo-code: `len(x) - len(remove(x, ch))`. Variations of this approach are useful in specific contexts.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate, finding the number of spaces in a string doesn't tell you how to find the number of instances of a specific character in a string. Someone searching up character count won't be looking for space count.

Comment: Because you can use `myName.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 == "e" ? 1 : 0) }`.

Comment: And that completely ignores that someone searching up character count won't be looking for space count.

Comment: @JoshCorreia Now you are the one who didn't read  "... has associated this post with a similar question." Isn't it? If you are worried about someone not finding it feel free to edit the title of the question marked as similar.

Comment: How is `isWhitespace` going to help someone count the occurrences of a specific character? It would not be appropriate to edit the title of the other question because they would make all of the answers no longer applicable.

Comment: Maybe you should read my comment again, carefully

Comment: @Joakim How does your comment have anything to do with someone looking up character count? Sure it answers the question of how to count characters, but doesn't help someone find the answer to their question if they're not looking to count spaces.

Comment: Since when is the letter 'e' a space? Please understand that I am only trying to help you see that the other question holds an answer to your question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the occurrences of a specific character all you have to do is use the [filter()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method like so:

```
var myName = "Jane Doe"
let numOccurrences = myName.filter{ $0 == "e" }.count
print(numOccurrences) // prints out 2
```

`.filter` will iterate over every character in the string, denoted by `$0`, and then return a list of all characters that are equal to the character "e". All you have to do after that is use `.count` to get the number of total occurrences.